# rebuild shimano wheel

Tags: wheels, shimano, rims, wheel-building

I've dented the rim on my Shimano WH-RS-10 rear wheel. I found the [tech doc pdf](http://techdocs.shimano.com/media/techdocs/content/cycle/EV/bikecomponents/WH/EV-WH-RS10-R-2746F_v1_m56577569830686101.pdf). I've had wheels rebuilt before but always with rims that were available to consumers. I can't find any place that sells the Shimano rim, nipples, or spokes to rebuild this wheel. I know I can get close matches from other companies, but I'm looking for identical components to match the good front wheel I have. Does Shimano actually provide these components for sale? Would this be something my LBS could order?

Comment: I've been going through my own wheel problems at the moment, trying to get spare parts for a fancy wheelset. But you should take heart from my experience - I chatted to a mechanic yesterday and he said that his shop will now _only_ stock Shimano wheels on the basis that these are the only manufacturer that they can _reliably_ source spare parts. That seemed quite scary to me, but that's what he said. His priority is not sales, but after-sales.

Comment: That may be true, for his shop. It is not true for any other shop I know of. DT Swiss, Mavic, Zipp, SRAM, Syncros, Xentis, Lightweight, and Profile Design all make replacement parts readily available. It is usually the shop choosing not to stock them, for (very legitimate) cost/benefit reasons.

Comment: Probably cheaper/better to just order a new wheel.  Save the old for spare parts.

Comment: @PeteH - "Loose" rims and other wheel parts are not as readily available as they once were -- it's cheaper to buy a new wheel in most cases, so there's little market -- but they're still easy to find.  Other wheelsets are often a hybrid of, say, Mavic rims, DT spokes, and (probably) Shimano hubs, built to the bike manufacturer's specs.

Comment: @zenbike - I phoned this guy's shop deliberately because they were listed on the DT Swiss site as authorised dealers (I was specifically looking for an Aerolite spoke). Whilst I could quite easily have got a box of 72 spokes, I drew a complete blank trying to find someone in the UK who could sell me a half dozen.

Comment: @PeteH: Prowheelbuilder.com will sell you spokes per piece. Most shops can't, because we are forced to buy the box of 100, and it is unlikely to be needed again, soon enough to make the cost worth the buy. Thats exactly what I meant when I said the shop was choosing not to stock them.

Comment: @zenbike yeah, totally understand this. In the end I bought from wheelbuilder.com (didn't need the "pro" version!!) and Fedex did me proud - ordered from Ca Monday eve, with me Thurs am, and on the bike Thurs pm (having never changed a spoke before). But all kinda weird that I live in the UK and have to buy Swiss spokes from the US - they've probably travelled more miles already than they ever will fixed to my wheel!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can order replacement parts from an LBS who is, or has access to a Shimano distributor.

You are unlikely to find that rim or those spokes in stock, because they are unique to the wheel, and it is not cost effective for a shop to keep them on hand given the relatively small chance that someone will need them.

Ordering them, though, should be straightforward, and cost less than 200 dollars.

Comment: ok cool. I was hoping that a rebuild (rim, spokes, nipples, labor) would cost less than a new wheel, which I can find online for ~$120.

Comment: Unfortunately, handbuilding a wheel is usually only cost effective for really good (and therefore expensive) wheels, or when you need something specific or unique. Or if you do the work yourself.